# Issue while tying to pass array of class objects into html

Tags: go, goland

**Issue details**

When I try to write following line in html, it says:

> category_id is an unexported field of struct type Categories.Category

```
<option value="eded">{{ $element.category_id }}</option>
```

but when I try this `<option value="eded">{{ $element }}</option>` I get following results. therefore I can confirm data is being transferred successfully in html

[image]

**Category Handler code**

```
type PageProps struct {
    Categories []Category
}

type Category struct {
    category_id int
}

type CategorydHandler struct {
    PageData PageProps
}

func Instantiate(pageProps PageProps) *CategorydHandler {
    return &CategorydHandler{
        PageData: pageProps,
    }
}

func (pageData *CategorydHandler) GetCategories() []Category {
    query := "select * from tblcategory order by category_id"
    result, err := db.Query(query)
    for result.Next() {
        var objCategory Category
        result.Scan(&objCategory.category_id)
        pageData.PageData.Categories = append(pageData.PageData.Categories, objCategory)
    }
    return pageData.PageData.Categories
}
```

**main.go**

```
categories := objCategories.GetCategories()
```

**html code**

```
<select multiple type="text">
    {{ range $index, $element := .Categories }}
        <option value="eded">{{ $element }}</option>
    {{ end }}        
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is there, but you cannot access it by name, because it is not exported.

Export the field-

```
type Category struct {
    Category_id int  // Capitalize the field name to export it
}
```

Comment: but the struct you have mentioned has already been declared in Category Handler. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Capitalize the field name, so it can be accesses via reflection

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77068226/issue-while-trying-to-read-uploaded-file-through-ajax-in-goland